# php - mssql_fetch_array

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to update an MSSQL database through PHP, as shown in in the following code. The problem is that the first 5 lines of code are successfully being executed but the program is not entering in the while loop. I am sure that the array $items contains records.

```
function updateOrder($items, $cardNo){
    if($items){
        $orderid = generateGuid();
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO Orders (OrderId, OrderDate, OrderStatus, OrderCardNo, OrderDiscount, OrderVatRate, CustomerUsername) ";
        $query .= " VALUES ('".mssql_guid_string($orderid)."',".date('Y-m-d').", 'PE', '$cardNo', 0, 0.18, '$username')";
        $result = mssql_query($query) or die("Unable to place order"/*mssql_get_last_message()*/);


        while($row = mssql_fetch_array( $items )){
            $tmpId = generateGuid();
            $tmpPrice = getUserPrice($username, $row["ProductId"]);

            $query = "INSERT INTO Orders_Details (OrderDetailsId, ProductPrice, Qty, OrderId, ProductId)";
            $query .= "VALUES ('".mssql_guid_string($tmpId)."', $tmpPrice, '".$row["Qty"]."', '".mssql_guid_string($orderid)."', 0, 0.18, '".$row["ProductId"]."')";

            echo($query);
            $result = mssql_query($query) or die("Unable to place order"/*mssql_get_last_message()*/);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it doesn't enter the while loop, then no, there is nothing in `items`, no matter what you believe. How did you test if there was anything? Did you do a count? And how do you know that the while loop isn't being started, but not just terminating your program or similiar?

Answer (score 0):

mssql_fetch_array takes a parameter that is the return of a mssql_query : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-fetch-array.php. What is `$items`?

Comment: $item is a database result i am getting from another method. Which the data present in the $item is not being modified during this UPDATE

Comment: @user1137243, And are you 100% sure that it is a valid query? Can we see the query that creates $items?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I also found a solution. I split the 2 UPDATE actions into 2 different methods, and called the method that populates $items twice

Answer (score 0):

Something worng with $items in `while($row = mssql_fetch_array( $items ))` either it's having no value or you are sending wrong in `$items`

If items having any value like items id then run a select query for selecting items having id in `$items` and use return of  `mssql_query` in `mssql_fetch_array`

Answer (score 0):

could it be that the date should be escaped?

Code:

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO Orders (OrderId, OrderDate, OrderStatus, OrderCardNo, OrderDiscount, OrderVatRate, CustomerUsername) ";
 $query .= " VALUES ('".mssql_guid_string($orderid)."',".date('Y-m-d').", 'PE', '$cardNo', 0, 0.18, '$username')";
```

$query may look like:

```
INSERT INTO Orders (OrderId, OrderDate, OrderStatus, OrderCardNo, OrderDiscount,
   OrderVatRate, CustomerUsername) 
   VALUES ('100',2012-1-20,'PE','10', 0, 0.18, 'username')
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by separating the 2 UPDATE actions into two different methods and call the method that populates $items twice.

Answer (score -1):

The last query before `while($row = mssql_fetch_array( $items ))` is an `INSERT`, so `mssql_fetch_array()` will never fetch anything!

Comment: He's not iterating over `$result`, but `$ìtems` which is not being modified.